# Is there a need for custom Domain Models when using LINQ?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model

I'm working on an MVC application using LINQ-SQL to connect to my SQL Server database.

Currently when fetching data, I'm passing the properties of my LINQ objects over to a Domain Model, which I'm then creating properties of in my View Models.

For example my View Model might have the following properties:

```
public Models.UserModel user { get; set; }
public List<Models.CountryModel> countries { get; set; }
```

My Domain Models have exactly the same properties as my LINQ objects, and I copy these properties over like:

```
Models.UserModel user = new Models.UserModel();
user.Username = User.Username;
user.FirstName = User.FirstName;
user.LastName = User.LastName;
```

Where `user` is my `Models.UserModel` object, and `User` is my LINQ object mapped from the User database table.

As my Domain Model is exactly the same as my LINQ object, is there any advantage for me transferring this data over to a Domain Model, or would it be okay for me to just use LINQ objects in my View Model such as:

```
public User user { get; set; }
public List<Country> countries { get; set; }
```

What are the advantages of using a Domain Model? Is this purely to loosely couple with the database LINQ objects?

---

If there are advantages to using Domain Models, how would be best to structure these within my MVC application?

Should they be split off entirely at the "Models" folder level (for example a sub-folder "DomainModels" and "ViewModels") or coincide (such as "UserEditViewModel.cs" and "UserDomainModel.cs").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As my Domain Model is exactly the same as my LINQ object, is there any
>   advantage for me transferring this data over to a Domain Model, or
>   would it be okay for me to just use LINQ objects in my View Model such
>   as:

You could reference domain models in your view models in case they are **exactly** the same. I don't see any benefit of duplicating this logic except that in the real world they are never the same. You always have some view specific things such as validation or even display labels.  The advantage of having *pure* view models is that your application is no longer tied to your database structure. You could easily flip/flop data access technologies without modifying the UI part. I find it more maintainable to have this clear separation and always tend to make it in my applications.

Comment: So would my last code snippet be the best option? Is there no advantage to passing the objects first to a custom Domain Model? I think maybe I'm getting confused from working with n-tier applications where you'd have a Model layer passing values to the MVC layer

Comment: Your latest change helps me understand the purpose of a Domain Model. If I was to switch from using LINQ-SQL to using direct SqlCommands with stored procedures, I would then require a domain model, and would need to change all references in my View Models!

Comment: It sounds like unless I'm 100% certain my application will always use LINQ-SQL, I should use Domain Models. Do you have an example of how to structure these within my application alongside view models? Should they be split off entirely at the "Models" folder level (for example a sub-folder "DomainModels" and "ViewModels") or coincide (such as "UserEditViewModel.cs" and "UserDomainModel.cs"). Thanks for your help

Comment: In the `Models` folder of an ASP.NET MVC application I put only view models that I specifically design for my views. My domain models live in separate assembly which acts as a Data Access Layer. In more complex applications I also have a Service Layer which is where the real domain models live. In this case the LINQ models that live in the Data Access Layer are only some transport objects that are mapped to the real domain models. The MVC application is then talking only to the service layer and the real domain models which are always mapped to their corresponding view models.